# Products Weight not calculated at shipping

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods

Single products weight calculated perfectly, when i add three products, three products of weight not calculated. Am using WEBSHOPS MATRIX RATES

[image]

Comment: Have you upload Csv for shipping price ?

Comment: yes, i upload all price

Comment: my error is, single product weight calculated, when i add 2 products, 2 products of weight not calculated. Did you understand what i want try to tell you .

Comment: Have you try in default magento ?

Comment: default magento working okay. I am going to webshopps matrix for individual courier selection, like user enter zip code, wedshopps return zipcode based weight along cost. so user can  select courier.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/zDWlPbP.png

Comment: when i add 2kg of 2 products, the rates display only 1kg of products, which means 2kg of products weight not calculated

Comment: Bro, are u able to understand my communication.

Comment: Check 'Shopping Cart Price Rule' in admin i think any rule is applying so shipping price not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47442/discussion-between-jeeva-rathinam-and-s-h-patel).

Comment: let the join the chat

Comment: @SureshChikani Is possible can i enter weight as KG in webshopapps metrix rate, because Default UPS, FEDEX, DHL required products weight as KG, but i am using Grams for webshopapps metrix rate. Is possible can i use products weight as KG in webshopapps metrix rate.